# HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a query which is written in postgresql, ending with WHERE INS."InstanceId" = 1'''
I add this query to a python script and run the python script. In a test environment, this query is working without any error. But, it does not work in the production machine.

```
query= '''.....'''
...
if (cursor.fetchone()[0]>0):

    cursor.execute('SELECT column_name FROM table_name where column_2 IS NULL ')

    id=''

    for i in cursor.fetchall():

        id=id+','+str(i[0])

    execution('UPDATE',query + 'IN (' + id[1:] + ')')


execution('INSERT',query + '>' + str(cursor.fetchone()[0]))



the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....py", line 109, in <module>
    execution('UPDATE',query + 'IN (' + id[1:] + ')')                                                                                                                                cursorW.execute(query)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: operator does not exist: bigint = boolean
LINE 1: ... WHERE INS."InstanceId" = 1IN (148...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: The error states that you're trying to update a `boolean` field with a `bigint`. Postgres doesn't know how to implicitly convert from `bigint` to `boolean`. This error can be reported if an argument is out of position. It would be helpful to know the datatypes of the fields you're trying to update with `query`.

Comment: This is just bizarre code. To the point the problem is with: `WHERE INS."InstanceId" = 1IN ` which I'm guessing comes from `query= '''.....'''`  which I'm pretty sure is not actually what `query` is. If you want an answer then you need to provide a complete logical example. Also spend some time here [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).

Comment: If something works in your test environment but not in production, your test environment is broken. So really, the question isn't "Why doesn't this work in production?", but rather "Why *does* this work in the test environment?"

Comment: That said, are you using the same database in test and in production?

Comment: There is an alternative:  The production environment is broken. Was there a system change (addition or fix) which should have been applied to production, but has not yet?  Either way you need to discover where they differ, and which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You say that 'query' variable ends in `WHERE INS."InstanceId" = 1`, and then your code tacks on `IN (...` to the end of it.  That is clearly going to produce nonsense, which of course throws an error.  What is mysterious here is why your test system doesn't throw the error, not why your production system does.

The exact wording of the error message is not immediately obvious. The part `INS."InstanceId" = 1` is an equality test, and as such it yields a Boolean.  That Boolean is then tested to see if it is IN the specified list, which is apparently a list of bigints.  But a IN-list test is just a series of equality tests, so to implement it PostgreSQL looks for an equality operator between the list part (bigints) and the scalar part (Boolean).  But it cannot find such an equality operator.  This is what leads to the error message, 'operator does not exist: bigint = boolean'.  Why the order of "bigint" and "boolean" in the error message are different than the order they occur in the expression, I don't know.  But understanding that doesn't seem important to the overall issue.